# Unable to run cron job in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to run a simple cron job using the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol. I have no idea why the cron is not executing

I have added the following code to `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'cron_test_hookname', 'cron_test_function' );

function cron_test_function() {
    $email = 'kingrahulsarkar@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

    wp_mail('shanpro.2015@gmail.com', 'WP Crontrol', 'WP Crontrol rocks!', $headers);
}
```

`

And then, I have created the event as per the screenshot provided on https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/#description

`Hook Name`: cron_test_hookname

`Arguments`: Blank

`Next Run`: Now

`Recurrence`: Every 1 Minute

## EDIT

My goal is to run CRON anyhow, using or without using any plugins, please provide your suggestions with example, thanks.

Comment: Is your cron running at all? does anything else say NEXT RUN: NOW?

Comment: The cron is not running at all, and I have no idea why, is there any other way to run the cron without using any plugins, my goal is to run CRON anyhow, using or not using plugins

Comment: yeah will post answer in 2 minutes

Comment: Hey Santanu I am stuck with the same problem. I have done all the steps which was suggested by @WilliamTurner but I was unable to make it working. Can you let me know if anything worked out for you. I have this command in my dreamhost CRON `/usr/local/php72/bin/php /home/path_to_my_cron_file/wp-cron.php
 ` Thanks!!

Comment: Hey Bhanu, you need to change /home/path_to_my_cron_file/ to the actual path...

Answer (score 1):

First disable normal WP-CRON To do this, open the **wp-config.php** file in your main WordPress folder and add the following line before the "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */" line:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

If you're on CPANEL hosting then open up your dashboard. Go to Cron Jobs (usually near the bottom)

Change MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, MONTH, WEEKDAY TO * * * * *

Command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php71 /home/YOURUSERNAME/public_html/wp-cron.php
```

** The ea-php71 in the above command will need changing to your version of PHP as this is for PHP 7.1. You may also need to add a folder name after /public_html/ if your site is in a sub directory.

This should run the cron as a proper cron job. :)

Comment: So, do I need to keep the hook I have created as it is?

Comment: yeah, you can see it in the cron so its registered correctly! you just need to get your cron running.